# NodeJS - Generate a dynamic JSON from data received via database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database, azure-functions

I'm trying to generate dynamic JSON based on the dynamic structure defined in DB. But the function doesn't wait till the response is received from database.

**Expected JSON:**

```
{
    "ROOT_1": [
            {
                "ROOT_2.1": {
                    "column2.1": 1,
                    "column2.1.1": "XXX"
                },
                "ROOT_2.2": [
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.2.1": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.2.1": 12
                    }
                ],
                "ROOT_2.3": [
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.3.1": 21
                    },
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.3.1": 22
                    },
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.3.1": 23
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ROOT_2.1": {
                    "column2.1": 1,
                    "column2.1.1": "XXX"
                },
                "ROOT_2.2": [
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.2.1": 11
                    },
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.2.1": 12
                    }
                ],
                "ROOT_2.3": [
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.3.1": 21
                    },
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.3.1": 22
                    },
                    {
                        "column2.1": 1,
                        "column2.3.1": 23
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

**Actual JSON:**

```
{
  "ROOT_1": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

All the columns are generated from database and assigned as an object.

I tried promise for making the DB call and waiting for the response but the data doesn't bind. The await is calling before the response from DB.

```
async function getJSON(){
 for (var m = 0; m < masterDataList.length; m++) {
   var childObj = {};
   var childList = [];
   rootDataList.push(parseObjData(childObj, getChildList(null), masterDataList[m]));
   }

 await Promise.all(rootDataList).then(function () {
            context.res = {
            body: root
        };
        context.done();
    }, function () {
    return context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: APP_CODE + "Error fetching data"
    };
});
}
```

```
function parseObjData(dynamicObj, structureMapList, masterDataObj) {
  for (var sml = 0; sml < dynamicObj.length; sml++) {
  var rowDataPromise = getRowDataList(); //data that fetches from DB
  rowDataPromise.then(function (rowData) {
   parseObjData(rowData,structureMapList,masterDataObj);
  }, function () { });
 }
} 

function getRowDataList() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        req.query(sqlQuery).then(function (result) {
            return resolve(result.recordset);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Any suggestion would be great help...!!!

Answer (score 0):

This line `return rowData;` is not working as you are expecting it to work. You could have written it like this:

```
var row;
rowDataPromise.then(function (rowData) {
    row = rowData;
}, function () { });
return row;
```

And use async await with this function.

Comment: I have a recursive loop, with above I'm getting Cannot read property 'length' of undefined for row variable as the data is not assigned.

Comment: I am not seeing any recursion, where is it?

Comment: Edited my question.